# nextjs getServerSideProps vs API

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm trying to understand the main difference between getServerSideProps and just using useSWR inside of the page component. If I run something like this inside getServerSideProps:

```
export const getServerSideProps = async () => {

  try {
    const palettes = []
    const docRef = query(collection(db, 'palettes'), orderBy('likes', 'desc'), limit(16))
    const docData = await getDocs(docRef)
    docData.forEach((doc) => {
      palettes.push(doc.data())
    })

    if (!docData) {
      return {
        props: {
          data: { error: 'Failed to load palettes. Please refresh the page.'}
        }
      }
    } else {
      return {
        props: {
          data: { palettes }
        }
      }
    }

  } catch (e) {
    console.log('error:', e)
  }
}
```

It will run at build time and then on each request by the user when viewing/navigating to the page?

Then what would be the difference from just using useSWR or another API fetcher like:

```
export default function PaletteSlugs({ slug }) {
  const { data, error } = useSWR(`/api/palette/${slug}`, fetcher)
  return (
   {data}
  )
}
```

Also could this affect how many request/reads will happen on the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, using `getServerSideProps` will get the API data on the Node.js server, while the HTML page will be completely populated by Node.js on the server. If you try to open the page source in the browser you will see all data already exists in the page source, this will be better for SEO.

But with `useSWR` will get the data on the client-side like normal `fetch` and the data will be populated on the client-side.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, so when I get into user pages like profile/account, is it better to use an API to fetch user data, so that getServerSideProps is not passing sensitive information? This is my first go at using an API/Firebase with React/Nextjs.

Comment: Yes, `getServerSideProps` is working on the server so you can deal with sensitive data inside.